# rtmp link video url thumbnail generate using php

Tags: php, video, thumbnails, rtmp

I have to write a script for generating thumbnails of a video from rtmp url link using PHP.The video source file is of format rtmp://ser_rer/0945/ra_45 which is at remote server.How can i generate thumbnails using this video URL link and also How to calculate time duration of a particular rtmp url link video.

Answer (score -1):

Using [Ffmpeg Thumbnailer](http://code.google.com/p/ffmpegthumbnailer/) this should be doable.

```
ffmpegthumbnailer -i rtmp://xxxxxxx/mp4:xxx.mp4 -o /output/thumbnail.jpg
```

Comment: I Can't create video thumbnail using "ffmpegthumbnailer"

Comment: Please, How to use this code generate thumbnail? i can't..  help me